# Visual c++ 2015 redistr without windows update

Tags: installation, redistributable

I have Windows 8.1 rtm, and I want to install Visual C++ for visual studio 2015 redistr, but without updating windows because I dont want to be spyed by microsoft or find windows 10 on my pc. I know there are other questions about this but this one is "without update", so please dont mark this...

The redistr install stucks installing KB2999226. If I install KB2999226 alone, it says "not applicable to your machine". Someone sayd that it need KB2919355 (win 8.1 update1?) that I don't want to install for the reasons above...

After using the trick of this good guy https://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/1595468 , I forced the install of KB2999226. Now the redistr installation completes sucessfully, but its a false positive, there are no dlls.

I tryed  to copy 61 dlls from the redistr temp folders to system folders(32 and 64). Now the apps error message changed to "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)".

So I'd like or to make the installation functional or make the dlls i copyed works. Also I wonder if the win10 spying came to windows 8(and 7) AFTER the 8.1 update1... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for this:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587